# In Catan, should development cards be drawn one at a time?

Tags: catan

In Catan, multiple actions can be taken per turn, so multiple development cards can be drawn. However, I realized that if somebody has 9 VPs and the draw 2 development cards, they could get 11 VPs, but in tournament play where amount of VPs matter, drawing extra VPs would help. But technically, the person would have after drawing only 1 VP card, so the 2nd one was basically drawn after winning the game, which would be technically spending cards and getting an extra victory point after the game was won, so, my question is, should Development card be drawn one at a time to stop extra VPs?

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about having them count at the same time, instead of in the order they are bought. In the video game version I play, they automatically count in the order they're bought (so you wouldn't be able to buy additional ones after the winning one)--but that's not the board game.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Buying multiple Development Cards at once is a legal play.

The rules state this:

> **Build**
>
> Now you can build. Through building, you can increase your victory points, expand your road network, improve your resource production, and/or buy useful development cards. To build, you must pay specific combinations of resource cards (see the Building Costs Card). **Take the appropriate number of roads, settlements, and/or cities from your supply and place them on the game board. Keep development cards hidden in your hand.**

(Taken from this answer: [In Settlers of Catan, are all actions on the same turn simultaneous?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/52947/in-settlers-of-catan-are-all-actions-on-the-same-turn-simultaneous))

So, spending resources can be done in bulk, with no distinction between roads, villages/cities or development cards.

The Rules Almanac, an appendix to the [main rules book](https://www.catan.com/service/game-rules), has some clarifications and additional limitations to playing Development Cards. These are that you cannot play development cards on the turn you buy them, and can only play one development card per turn. VP cards are an exception to both of these rules however, as you don't play them but reveal them when you get to 10VP.

Although the almanac states that buying your tenth VP ends the game, it also allows for buying in bulk.

---

[The FAQ](https://www.catan.com/faq/4613-victory-conditions-may-i-continue-scoring-points-after-having-reached-number-victory-points) doesn't exactly clear things up either:

> **Victory Conditions**
>
> May I continue scoring points after having reached the number of victory points required for a win?
>
> **Answer**
>
> This could make sense in a private tournament where the scores from several games are added up. For individual games and official tournaments, the following applies: You have won as soon as you have reached the required number of victory points on your turn – and then the game is over.

Comment: That seems inconclusive. You can buy multiple but you should stop buying as you reached 10VP, because game ends at this point. Can you build several settlements / towns at the same turn to go over 10VP, or does the game end before you have a chance to build additional buildings? Whatever the answer is it would be logical it applies to the cards as well.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh If two development cards are considered to belong to a single *transaction*, then you could draw both before viewing them, see that one is a victory point, and keep both regardless of their order in the deck. The question is whether this concept of a transaction is valid for Catan.

Comment: @Grault That's my question, do you stop drawing once you get to 10 (Which would make it necessary to draw one development card at a time) or are they bought in bulk?

Comment: @BenjaminErickson IIRC my group plays with the idea that you can buy in bulk. I don't know whether the rules actually specify. I'm leaning toward single buys being more balanced.

Comment: @Grault The rules allow for buying in bulk, as stated in my answer.

Comment: @steenbergh None of what you listed says that.

Comment: @Grault Added emphasis on the rule that says to take the correct number of pieces (because you've bought them in bulk) from your supply and place them on the board. Though this deals with roads/settlements, the same applies for Development Cards as they are not excepted in this rule and are mentioned (in plural) in the very next sentence.

Comment: @steenbergh I'm not convinced the plural means that at all (or that the sentence structure corresponds with the sequence of game events), but either way I'm a little annoyed at the authors for lazy writing.

Comment: @steenbergh [Tournament Rule](https://www.catanstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Catan-Championship-Kit-Instructions-2020-Tournament-Rules-Web.pdf) suggest Bulk buying is not permissible. 2.13.

Answer (score 1):

The [Catan Studio](https://www.catanstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Catan-Championship-Kit-Instructions-2020-Tournament-Rules-Web.pdf) Tournament rules for national tournaments make clear points above 10 are irrelevant.

> 2.10 A player has won if they have 10 or more victory points **(although only 10 will be counted for the ranking)** and it is the player’s turn. If a player does not notice that they have 10 points, the player must wait until the next turn before winning the game (assuming no earlier player wins, and the player still has 10 points).

Note that this also contradicts the accepted wisdom of [Winning without Declaring](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/2468/does-a-player-win-catan-if-they-forget-to-count-their-points/3506#3506) from the standard Catan rules.

Comment: this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @BenjaminErickson only the tournament organisers can really help you then. Standard tournament rules make the question irrelevant, so if they are not using them, we cannot predict what else they are changing.

Comment: @Jonita it dosen't help as the tournament organizers are playing by 5th edition Catan rules only.